# ggvis - adjust legend color to fill color

Tags: r, legend, ggvis

The following code produces marks with fill colors ranging from red to yellow. 
the default legend however has a blue spectrum.

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>% 
ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, fill = ~disp, stroke = ~disp, strokeWidth := 2) %>%
layer_points() %>%
scale_numeric("fill", range = c("red", "yellow")) %>% 
add_legend("fill", orient = 'left')
```

How do I remove the default le from the top right corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default legend is for `stroke`, your custom one is for `fill`. If you instead set `stroke` to `"black"` in the `ggvis` line, the legend on the right will dissappear.

```
...ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, fill = ~disp, stroke := "black", strokeWidth := 2) %>% ...
```

[image]